Cannot get if statement to work in text based game
The following code implements a text-based game. The game consists of a cave and several rooms inside it, where the player can move and get items.
However, I cannot reach the code under the if current_room == "Villain's Lair": condition, even if I successfully reach the Villain's Lair room.
def display_instructions():
    # print a main menu and the commands
    print('Welcome to Colossal Cave Adventure Remake')
    print('Move commands: South, North, East, West')
    print('Collect 9 items before encountering the Dragon or be eaten by the Dragon.')
    print('Move commands: South, North, East, West, Exit & Get Item')
    print('To add item to inventory use: Get item')
    
display_instructions()

# The starting room
current_room = 'Cave Entrance'
inventory = []
move = ''
directions = ['North', 'South', 'East', 'West', 'Exit', 'Get Item']
item_key = 'item'
villain = 'Dragon'

# Define room connections
rooms = {
  'Cave Entrance': {'South': 'Troll Region', 'North': 'Giants Room', 'East': 'Magnificent Caverns', 'West': 'Pearl Room' },
  'Giants Room': {'item': 'Golden Eggs', 'East': 'Hall of Mists', 'West': 'Forest Region', 'South': 'Cave Entrance'},
  'Hall of Mists': {'item': 'Diamonds', 'West': 'Giants Room'},
  'Forest Region': {'item': 'Magic Staff', 'South': 'Volcano Region', 'East': 'Giants Room'},
  'Volcano Region': {'item': 'Ring of Doom', 'North': 'Forest Region'},
  'Pearl Room': {'item': 'Magic Pearl', 'East': 'Cave Entrance', 'North': 'Pirates Room'},
  'Pirates Room': {'item': 'Pirates Chest', 'South': 'Pearl Room'},
  'Magnificent Caverns': {'item':'Trident', 'South': 'Plover Room', 'West': 'Cave Entrance'},
  'Plover Room': {'item': 'Emeralds', 'North': 'Magnificent Caverns'},
  'Troll Region': {'item': 'Golden Chain', 'North': 'Cave Entrance', 'East': "Villain's Lair"},
  "Villain's Lair": {'villain': 'Dragon', 'West': 'Troll Region'} # Villain's Lair
}

def user_status():  # indicate room and inventory contents
    print('\n-------------------------')
    print(f'You are in the {current_room}.')
    print(f'Your inventory is {inventory}.')

    if 'item' in rooms[current_room]:
         print(f"In this room you see {rooms[current_room]['item']}.")
    else:
        print("This room is empty.")

    print('-------------------------------')

#While loop for game play
while move != 'Exit':
    user_status()

    move = str(input('Make a move, Get item or Exit to quit: \n')).title().strip()

    if move not in directions:
        print('Invalid Input. Try Again!')
        continue

    # Code to get item
    if move == 'Get Item':
        if 'item' in rooms[current_room]:
            inventory.append(rooms[current_room]['item'])
            # Delete item from dictionary
            del rooms[current_room]['item']
        else:
            print("There's no item here.")


    #if encounter villain in room
    if current_room == "Villain's Lair":
         # If You Lose
        if len(inventory) < 9:
            print('You lost the fight with the Dragon.')
            break
        #If You Win
        else:
            print('You won! You beat the Dragon! Congratulations!')
            break


    # If you want to exit game
    elif move == 'Exit':
        print("You've exited the game. Bye! Thanks for playing!")
        break

    # If Move Is Right Direction
    if move in rooms[current_room]:
        current_room = rooms[current_room][move]
    else:
        # If Wrong Direction
        print("You have a wall in the way. Try again")

When running the program, the following inputs in the specified order would bring the player to the Villain's Lair, with an empty inventory, so at least a You lost the fight with the Dragon. message should appear:

South
East

I need to have the player win or lose upon entering determined by the amount of items in inventory. The code does nothing at all when I enter the Villian's Lair, just printing the status but no other success or error message appears.
Can someone please tell me why the code inside the 'problematic' if is not running?

Please narrow it down. What if statement exactly? You have multiple. Please remove anything unnecessary to demonstrate the issue and present just a [mre].

"I can't get the if statement for entering the dragon's lair to work" won't normally be solved by trial-and-error with indents.  What exactly are you having trouble with?   Please include the sample inputs to get your issue.

I ran your code and got an IndentationError: expected an indented block after 'if' statement on line 63. Maybe this helps

The problem you have is that the while loop starts with an input just after printing the status, so the flow is blocked and the if you mention only runs after you do a 'move' again (even if already being in the Villain's Lair. You need to move that if to the top of the while. As the code is, the if will run if you do a valid move when being already in the Villain's Lair.

I've moved the the encountering villain code to the top but still does nothing.

@Dcommand I have saved a working version in this Pastebin: https://pastebin.com/iSScXT1P. Please, check the differences with your code and understand the reasoning behind the changes. It's basically a change in the way code is organised inside the main loop. I have run it and managed to both lose and win the game, so all scenarios should be covered.

Why is "Can someone help me?" not a useful question?

Note that exit is inside and elif instead of a regular if. So you cannot exit if you are in the villains lair because the elif won't trigger.

It is very useful to try running the code in your head while you program. In this case, with such a small piece of code, you can easily see that your while loop does these steps:

Print the user status.
Ask for user input.
Check if input is valid.
Check if input command is 'Get Item' and react to it.
Check the end-game room and print ending message.
Check if input command is 'Exit' and react to it.
Check any other input command, which would be to move to another room.

Steps 5 and 7 are the ones causing the strange behaviour in your code. The reason is that, between changing room (step 7) and checking the end-game room (step 5), a user input (step 2) needs to happen.
This means that, with the code you have right now, when you reach the Villain's Lair an input will be requested before actually printing a success message.
I would suggest you to slightly change the steps' order, so that you can get the desired behaviour. A more logical order would be:

Print the user status.
Ask for user input.
Check if input is valid.
Check if input command is 'Exit' and react to it.
Check if input command is 'Get Item' and react to it.
Check any other input command, which would be to move to another room.
Check the end-game room, print ending message and exit loop.

That being said, the following code would work as expected:
def display_instructions():
    # print a main menu and the commands
    print('Welcome to Colossal Cave Adventure Remake')
    print('Move commands: South, North, East, West')
    print('Collect 9 items before encountering the Dragon or be eaten by the Dragon.')
    print('Move commands: South, North, East, West, Exit & Get Item')
    print('To add item to inventory use: Get item')
    
display_instructions()

# The starting room
current_room = 'Cave Entrance'
inventory = []
move = ''
directions = ['North', 'South', 'East', 'West', 'Exit', 'Get Item']
item_key = 'item'
villain = 'Dragon'

# Define room connections
rooms = {
  'Cave Entrance': {'South': 'Troll Region', 'North': 'Giants Room', 'East': 'Magnificent Caverns', 'West': 'Pearl Room' },
  'Giants Room': {'item': 'Golden Eggs', 'East': 'Hall of Mists', 'West': 'Forest Region', 'South': 'Cave Entrance'},
  'Hall of Mists': {'item': 'Diamonds', 'West': 'Giants Room'},
  'Forest Region': {'item': 'Magic Staff', 'South': 'Volcano Region', 'East': 'Giants Room'},
  'Volcano Region': {'item': 'Ring of Doom', 'North': 'Forest Region'},
  'Pearl Room': {'item': 'Magic Pearl', 'East': 'Cave Entrance', 'North': 'Pirates Room'},
  'Pirates Room': {'item': 'Pirates Chest', 'South': 'Pearl Room'},
  'Magnificent Caverns': {'item':'Trident', 'South': 'Plover Room', 'West': 'Cave Entrance'},
  'Plover Room': {'item': 'Emeralds', 'North': 'Magnificent Caverns'},
  'Troll Region': {'item': 'Golden Chain', 'North': 'Cave Entrance', 'East': "Villain's Lair"},
  "Villain's Lair": {'villain': 'Dragon', 'West': 'Troll Region'} # Villain's Lair
}

def user_status():  # indicate room and inventory contents
    print('\n-------------------------')
    print(f'You are in the {current_room}.')
    print(f'Your inventory is {inventory}.')

    if 'item' in rooms[current_room]:
         print(f"In this room you see {rooms[current_room]['item']}.")
    else:
        print("This room is empty.")

    print('-------------------------------')

# While loop for game play
while True:
    # 1. Print the user status
    user_status()

    # 2. Ask for user input
    move = str(input('Make a move, Get item or Exit to quit: \n')).title().strip()

    # 3. Check if input is valid
    if move not in directions:
        print('Invalid Input. Try Again!')
        continue

    # 4. Check if input command is 'Exit' and react to it
    if move == 'Exit':
        print("You've exited the game. Bye! Thanks for playing!")
        break

    # 5. Check if input command is 'Get Item' and react to it
    if move == 'Get Item':
        if 'item' in rooms[current_room]:
            inventory.append(rooms[current_room]['item'])
            # Delete item from dictionary
            del rooms[current_room]['item']
        else:
            print("There's no item here.")

    # 6. Check any other input command, which would be to move to another room
    elif move in rooms[current_room]:
        current_room = rooms[current_room][move]

    # 6.1. React to invalid movement
    else:
        print("You have a wall in the way. Try again")


    # 7. Check the end-game room, print ending message and exit loop
    if current_room == "Villain's Lair":
         # If You Lose
        if len(inventory) < 9:
            print('You lost the fight with the Dragon.')
        #If You Win
        else:
            print('You won! You beat the Dragon! Congratulations!')

        break

Hope it helps! :)
